# Sidekiq worker does not triggered as a AR callback on Heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

In my Rails 6 app I've got ActiveRecord callback (`after_create`) which should call `SyncProductsWorker` (Sidekiq worker) each time when record `ProductsBatch` is created:

`ProductsBatch` model with after_create:

```
module Imports
  class ProductsBatch < ImportsRecord
    attr_accessor :product_codes

    after_create :enqueue

    def enqueue
      ::Imports::SyncProductsWorker.perform_async(product_codes, self.id)
    end
  end
end

# base class for the above model
class ImportsRecord < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true

  connects_to database: { writing: :imports }
end
```

`SyncProductsWorker` class:

```
module Imports
  class SyncProductsWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options queue: 'imports_sync'

    def perform(list, id)
      # do some things
    end
  end
end
```

`config/sidekiq.yml`

```
:max_retries: 16
:queues:
- default
- imports_sync
- imports_fetch_all
:dynamic: true
```

`config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`

```
redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE } }

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = redis
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = redis
end
```

Everything works well locally but when I deploy code into Heroku worker doesn't seem to call. The strange thing is that, based on Heroku logs, it doesn't even work when I try to call it directly from Heroku rails console:

```
heroku run rails console --app test-app                                                                      
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.47.7 to 7.60.2.
Running rails console on ⬢ test-app... up, run.8489 (Hobby)
Loading production environment (Rails 6.1.4.1)
irb(main):013:0> ::Imports::SyncProductsWorker.perform_async(['11'], 10)
=> "5edf93e27fa2f41245587d49"
```

But nothing happens inside Heroku logs:

```
2022-06-06T22:02:00.240650+00:00 app[worker.1]: [ActiveJob] [ProductAvailabilityAdjusterJob] [25c15f9d-e032-438e-bda8-16ffd557cc32] Performed ProductAvailabilityAdjusterJob (Job ID: 25c15f9d-e032-438e-bda8-16ffd557cc32) from Sidekiq(default) in 5.44ms
2022-06-06T22:02:00.240789+00:00 app[worker.1]: pid=4 tid=2xbk class=ProductAvailabilityAdjusterJob jid=91ad7e69e061df9f2f681ef3 elapsed=0.006 INFO: done
```

Is there anything special I should do to make this worker work on Heroku?

Comment: did you add Redis add-on and do you have this added "web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb" in procfile as well?

Comment: @ManojMenon yup, it's already there.

Comment: Do you have something like `worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C config/sidekiq.yml` in your procfile? And was it also deployed with the changes? BTW: You shouldn't use `after_create` because at this point the record is not created yet - use `after_create_commit` instead.